# In JSF what is the shortest way to output List<SomeObj> as comma separated list of "name" properties of SomeObj

Tags: jsf, facelets

I have a question about outputing a list of objects as a comma separated list in JSF.

Let's say:

```
public class SomeObj {
  private String name;
  ... constructors, getters and setters ...
}
```

and List<SomeObj>:

```
List<SomeObj> lst = new ArrayList<SomeObj>();
lst.add(new SomeObj("NameA"));
lst.add(new SomeObj("NameB"));
lst.add(new SomeObj("NameC"));
```

to output it as a listbox I can use this code:

```
<h:selectManyListbox id="id1"
                  value="#{listHolder.selectedList}">
  <s:selectItems value="#{listHolder.lst}"
                   var="someObj"
                 label="#{someObj.name}"/>
  <s:convertEntity />
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

But what is the easiest way to output the list as is, comma seperated ? Like this:

```
NameA, NameB, NameC
```

Should I use JSTL <c:forEach/> or may be the <s:selectItems/> tag can also be used ?

Comment: Don't tag `jsp` if you're using `facelets`. Those are two entirely distinct view technologies, Facelets being less or more the successor of JSP when talking in JSF context. I've retagged accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `<ui:repeat>` (from facelets). It's similar to `c:forEach`

Or pre-compute the comma-separated string in the managed bean, and obtain it via a getter.

Comment: I think he's not using Facelets since he explicitly tagged JSP.

Comment: sometimes they tag so just because a `.jsp` extension is used (with facelets inside) :)

Comment: @Vitaly Polonetsky use `ui:repeat` and use the inner part from BalusC's answer

Answer (score 26):

Given a `List<Person> persons` where `Person` has a `name` property,

- If you're already on Java EE 7 with EL 3.0, then use EL stream API.

  ```
  #{bean.persons.stream().map(p -> p.name).reduce((p1, p2) -> p1 += ', ' += p2).get()}
  ```
- If you're not on EL 3.0 yet, but have JSF 2.x at hands, then use Facelets `<ui:repeat>`.

  ```
  <ui:repeat value="#{bean.persons}" var="person" varStatus="loop">
      #{person.name}#{not loop.last ? ', ' : ''}
  </ui:repeat>
  ```
- Or if you're still on jurassic JSP, use JSTL `<c:forEach>`.

  ```
  <c:forEach items="#{bean.persons}" var="person" varStatus="loop">
      ${person.name}${not loop.last ? ', ' : ''}
  </c:forEach>
  ```

#### See also:

- [How iterate over List<T> and render each item in JSF Facelets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098626/how-iterate-over-listt-and-render-each-item-in-jsf-facelets)
- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: Am I correct in that this requires JSF 2.0, i.e. varStatus is not supported for JSF 1.2 with facelets?

Comment: @meriton: Yes, you're correct. The `c:forEach` should however work by `xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"`.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Being a tag handler, c:forEach won't work for me, since the number of repetitions changes after the view is constructed. But I found another way (which I added as answer).

Comment: @meriton: nice one! Yes, I should have added that JSTL only runs at view build time.

Comment: Awesome. A lambda string joiner in one line for JSF EL... As usual, crazy stuff coming from BalusC is rather rare. 

Answer (score 5):

If you can't use `varStatus` because you're stuck with using JSF 1.2, you can do:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{listHolder.lst}" var="someObj">#{someObj != listHolder.lst[0] ? ',' : ''}
#{someObj.name}</ui:repeat>
```

The absence of whitespace around the EL-expressions is deliberate, we don't want a space to appear there in the rendered HTML.

Comment: I think it should be:
`<ui:repeat value="#{listHolder.lst}" var="someObj">#{someObj != listHolder.lst[listHolder.lst.size()-1] ? ',' : ''}
#{someObj.name}</ui:repeat>`